# TypeError ".deploy()" is not a function hardhat

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I just started learning Solidity and trying to make my first app with the help of a youtube tutorial.

But I'm getting the below issue:

```
TypeError: transactions.deployed is not a function
at main (D:\\one-more-try(8.16)\\smart-contract\\scripts\\deploy.js:5:22)  
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)  
at runMain (D:\\one-more-try(8.16)\\smart-contract\\scripts\\deploy.js:12:5)
```

I'm following the same suggestions from the tutorial.

Here is my `deploy.js` script to deploy using hardhat.

```
const main = async () => {
  const Transactions = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Transactions");
  const transactions = await Transactions.deploy();

  await transactions.deployed();

  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactions.address);
};

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

runMain();
```

and solidity code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract Transactions {
    uint256 transactionCounter;
    event Transfer(address from, address receiver, uint amount, string message, uint256 timestamp, string keyword);

    struct TransferStruct{
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint amount; 
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string keyword;
    }

    TransferStruct[] transactions;

    function addToBlockchain(address payable receiver, uint amount, string memory message, string memory keyword) public{
        transactionCounter += 1;
        transactions.push(TransferStruct(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword));

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword);
    }

    function getAllTransactions() public view returns (TransferStruct[] memory){
        return transactions;
    }

    function getTransactionCounter() public view returns(uint256){
        return transactionCounter;
    }
 }
```

When I try to deploy to `goerli` testnet, I'm getting `undefined` in my transaction address after the smart contract is deployed.

```
#npx hardhat run --network goerli scripts/deploy.js
Transactions address:  undefined
```

Comment: Can you please share the environment you run the code(locally, remix, etc.) with us? In case you locally please also include the package.json & hardhat.config.ts / hardhat.config.js

Comment: Can you share your `hardhat.config.js` file?

Comment: Hello @AlonBenYaakov, I use VisualStudioCode  here is my hardhat.config.js `require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

module.exports ={
  solidity: '0.8.0',
  networks: {
    goerli:{
      url: 'https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/9hdbUY56AG1vSSbFp8QdMl244byDyz9K',
      accounts:['0910b9a78492012d4792b3efa407b7401b4d5ab87fa173a5f6ffe81caa4f723b']
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @AlonBenYaakov and package.json ` {   "name": "smart-contract",   "version": "1.0.0",   "description": "",   "main": "deploy.js",,   "scripts": {     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   },   "keywords": [],   "author": "",   "license": "ISC",   "devDependencies": {     "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",     "hardhat": "^2.17.1"   } }`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox. In a recent update hardhat team migrated from hardhat-waffle to @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox. So deployed() is no longer in use.

To make your code work replace deployed() with waitForDeployment().

You can refer to this : [Migration](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle)